# Vertical timeline not worked in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I use vertical timeline for ruby on rails application. That works well except chrome browser. Animation not works in google chrome. I think this is from script!!!!. can anyone suggest the solution. my script as,

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var timelineBlocks = $('.cd-timeline-block'),
        offset = 0.8;

    //hide timeline blocks which are outside the viewport
    hideBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset);

    document.getElementById("body").onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    //on scolling, show/animate timeline blocks when enter the viewport
    function myFunction() {
        (!window.requestAnimationFrame) 
            ? setTimeout(function(){ showBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset); }, 100)
            : window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){ showBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset); });
    }

    function hideBlocks(blocks, offset) {
        blocks.each(function(){
            ( $(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*offset ) && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').addClass('is-hidden');
        });
    }

    function showBlocks(blocks, offset) {
        blocks.each(function(){
            ( $(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*offset && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('is-hidden') ) && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('bounce-in');
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `document.getElementById("body").onscroll = function() {myFunction()};` that's not working properly on chrome.

Use this script for onScroll Event:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    (!window.requestAnimationFrame) 
        ? setTimeout(function(){ showBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset); }, 100)
        : window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){ showBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset); });
});
```

Reference: https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/

Let me know your feedback!
Thanks

Comment: Ya ... worked well. Sorry I have not enough reputation to upvote this question. But this works good. Thanks